# FileZilla: preserve UTF-8 encoding when transferring to Linux

Tags: linux, filezilla, character-encoding

Is there a way to set FileZilla to preserve the existing encoding of my text files, which are UTF-8, when transferring from Windows to a Linux server? In the FileZilla Site Manager, I have selected the Charset tab and chosen Use custom charset, and filled in UTF-8.

On the server, I can inspect the file with

```
file -i myfile.html
```

and it shows

```
myfile.html: text/html; charset=unknown-8bit.
```

Further, if I try to use iconv, it requires an input encoding. Trying

```
iconv -f unknown-8bit -t UTF-8 myfile.html
```

I get the error

```
iconv: conversion from `unknown-8bit' is not supported
```

If I try

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 myfile.html
```

I get

```
illegal input sequence at position 344
```

which is the first position of a non ascii character.

Comment: I have it working now. Something went wrong on the Windows side where I created the text file. I had set the encoding type to UTF-8 but that setting apparently did not stick. (I'll don't know why.)  I set it again, did the transfer, and now the encoding is correct in the Linux file.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot you just transfer them in a binary mode?

*Transfer > Transfer type > Binary*.

Comment: That could help, though I did not try it. I finally did get the transfer to work - see my comment on the OP. Thanks.